# Find the Taylor series centered at $z_0$ of the function $f(z) = \sin(z^2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series centered at $ z_0$ of the function $f(z) = \sin(z^2)$.

Solution:
$z$ is replaced by $z^2$ in the well-known expansion

$$ \sin z =
\sum_{n=0}^{ +\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\qquad ( \forall z \in \mathbb C). $$ Thus,
$$ f(z) = \sin (z^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{ +\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(z^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{ +\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!} \qquad( \forall z \in \mathbb C). $$ Is this correct?
I leave the exercise until there? If the procedure is wrong or if you have to continue developing, I hope you can help me.

Comment: The issue is that this is not centred at $z_0$

Comment: $z^2=(z-z_0+z_0)^2=(z-z_0)^2+2(z-z_0)z_0+z^2_0$. You may then use the identities for sin of sum of arguments.

Comment: Let $w=z-z_0$. Then $\sin(z^2)=\sin(z_0\!^2+2z_0w+w^2)$, and you can use the angle addition formulas to write this as a combination of $\sin(2z_0w),\cos(2z_0w),\sin(w^2),\cos(w^2)$. Expand these as series in $w$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz & myself - Wait, this isn't a linear combination with constant coefficients. The series involving $2z_0w$ and $w^2$ must be multiplied together. Can that be done easily?

Comment: @mr_e_man: nowhere did I say anything about linear combinations. In fact it is going to be a little tedious to get the terms in the right order ( Cauchy product).

Comment: @OliverDiaz. I don't know if you could even obtain the general formula

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\sin(z)=(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/2i$ allows considerable simplification, at the level of hand computation.

Namely, it suffices to know the power series of $e^{iz}$ at $z_o$, for which we have the Taylor-Maclaurin-Cauchy expansion
$$
e^{iz} \;=\; \sum_{n\ge 0} {d^n\over dz^n}e^{iz}\Big|_{z_o} {1\over n!} (z-z_o)^n
$$
and the derivative is easy to understand... :)

EDIT: depending on exactly what one wants, replacing $z$ by $z^2$ in a power series expansion may be "good". Or, sure, possibly replacing $z-z_o$ by $z^2-z_o$ and then doing the ugly algebra is what's demanded. My point is that this is feasible, by hand computation, but that the more details one wants, in awkward variants, the more unpleasant the computations become. My sincere reaction to such a question is "yes, I could compute those coefficients in finite time" (and maybe some comments about rationality)...

Comment: But the OP is interested in $\sin(z^2)$.

Comment: @Gary, true, but... :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a very tedious work and I am not sure that we could obtain the general formula.

As said in comments, let $z=y+a$ $(a=z_0)$ and consider that you look for the imaginary part of the expansion of
$$\exp\big[i(a^2+2a y+y^2) \big]=e^{ia^2} \, e^{2iay}\,e^{iy^2}$$ that is to say
$$\big[\cos(a^2)+i\,\sin(a^2)\big]\Bigg[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(2iay)^n}{n!}\Bigg]\Bigg[\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac {(iy^2)^m}{m!}\Bigg]$$ where the Cauchy product appears in a clear manner.

Using $c=\cos(a^2)$ and $s=\sin(a^2)$, the first coefficients would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \alpha_n \\
 0 & s \\
 1 & 2 a c \\
 2 & c-2 a^2 s \\
 3 & -\frac{4 }{3}c a^3-2 s a \\
 4 & \frac{1}{6} \left(4 a^4-3\right) s-2 a^2 c
\end{array}
\right)$$